# Background Task on windows runtime app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a wp runtime app. 
I have a question on BackgroundTaskBuilder. The msnd example says a buildt-in/certains types of trigger can be set into the builder object, so when a system event happens, the background task triggers. Also it says a Run method is an entrypoint of background task, does that mean I have to implement Run method in order to trigger a background task in other types of trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You create a class which implements IBackgroundTask (specifically IBackgroundTask.Run) and register that class with the BackgroundTaskBuilder. When the trigger occurs the class's Run method will be called.